# Opening a new page: New window vs. New tab

Tags: javascript, ruby, webrick

I have my web browser (Firefox 10 and Chrome 16) set so that when a new page opens, it is opened within the same window in a new tab. When I write a local file like this:

```
<html><body><input type="button" onclick="window.open();"/></body></html>
```

and access that location from a web browser and click the button, the new page opens **within the same window in a new tab**. That is expected.

However, when I use a local webserver (Ruby + Webrick) and dynamically generate the same thing as above, and access that location `localhost:3000`, and click the button, then the new page opens **in a new window**. Why does it behave differently from above, and how can I fix the code so that it opens **within the same window in a new tab**?

If I instead do

```
<html><body><input type="button" onclick="window.open("", "_self");"/></body></html>
```

then the new page opens **in the same tab, i.e., overwrites the current page**.

Comment: Not clear about how you generate the page. I tried to serve the page from local web server (mongoose) directly and it works as expected to open window in new tab

Comment: @rogerz I see. I will update if I notice something. Thanks so far for trying.

Answer (score 2):

In general if you provide dimensions with `window.open` you get a new window. If you don't you get a new tab.

I would imagine specifying `_self` does the same.